# Inherit constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I have a class named `myGraph` which is derived from `graph`

If I know the number of vertices when I call the constructor, I will be able to use the following constructor.

```
myGraph(int numOfV) : graph(numOfV)
{
    // initialize...
}
```

I want to compute the number of vertices in the constructor and then inherit `graph` **inside** the constructor. How to do so?

```
myGraph(int a, int b)
{
    /* using a,b to initialize...  
       a sequence of push operation on (vector<T>)verticeList */

    int numOfV = this->verticeList.size();
    // inherit...
    myGraph(numOfV);  // it will not work


}
```

Please note that

1. the procedure I use to compute the number of vertices is complicated.(many lines of code rather than `a+b`)
2. the number of vertices depends on the instance variables in `myGraph`, so I need to initialize the members of `myGraph` first and then inherit the remaining `graph` part.

Answer (score 3):

If there's a lot of logic going on pre-initialization, you can separate that in a method:

```
struct myGraph
{
    myGraph(int a, int b) : graph(myGraph::computeNoVertices(a,b))
    {
    }
    static int computeNoVertices(int a, int b)
    {
        //whole chunk of code 
    }
};
```

Comment: This is usually the answer to this type of problem.  If you additionally need to use other members as lvalues during initialization, you can move those members to a private base struct.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call base class constructor at derived class's member initialization list:

```
 myGraph(int a, int b) :graph(a +b)
 {                     //^^It is OK to do computation when you pass parameters to
                       //base class constructor
    // do something...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

With C++11, you can do a limited amount of this:

```
myGraph(int a, int b)
  : myGraph(a+b)
{
}
```

If your calculations are much more sophisticated, you'll want to break them out into a separate function though:

```
myGraph(int a,int b)
  : myGraph(calculateNumOfV(a,b))
{
}
```

Comment: call another constructor of the same class? delegate?

Comment: He wants to call the `graph` constructor, not delegate to another `myGraph` constructor.

Comment: @Praetorian: maybe, but his example makes it look like he's wanting to call the other constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> the number of vertices depends on the instance variables in myGraph, so I need to initialize the members of myGraph first and then inherit the remaining graph part.

That is not possible. **Base classes are *always* initialized before data members**. However, during construction the values you assign to your members depend solely on the constructor arguments, so the base class' constructor parameters depend only on those arguments as well.

Let's say you have members `m1` and `m2` and want to initialize the base class with values dependent on those two members, say `f(m1,m2)` and `g(m1,m2)`. Your constructor has the parameters `a`, `b`, `c` and you initialize `m1` and `m2` dependent on those ctor arguments, with `x(a,b,c)` and `y(a,b,c)`. Then the ctor should look like this:

```
class Foo : Bar {
  int m1;
  int m2;
  static int x(int a, int b, int c);
  static int y(int a, int b, int c);
public:
  Foo(int a, int b, int c) 
    : Bar( f(x(a,b,c), y(a,b,c)), g(x(a,b,c), y(a,b,c)) )
    , m1(x(a,b,c))
    , m2(y(a,b,c)) 
  {}
};
```

Of course, to improve readability, you can always create more static functions to calculate the initializer for the base object:

```
class Foo : Bar {
  /* ... */
  static Bar calcBar(int a, int b, int c) {
    int i1 = x(a,b,c);
    int i2 = y(a,b,c);
    return Bar(f(i1,i2), g(i1,i2));
  }

public:
  Foo(int a, int b, int c) 
    : Bar( calcBar(a,b,c) )
    , m1(x(a,b,c))
    , m2(y(a,b,c)) 
  {}
};
```